# Interface code to handle Arduino Motor Controller and Odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, encoders, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am building a robot based off of a electric wheelchair with an Arduino as the motor controller and odometry interface. My question is this: **Is there a package already existing that reads odometry from the Arduino and publishes it to TF and sends twist commands to the Arduino?** I looked at the differential_drive package [on github](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge), but it uses another board as an interface to the encoders. I have photo interrupters on my robot that I would like to use instead and I have them working with the Arduino. They change state when the encoder wheel's teeth are blocking the IR beam or not. The reason I want to use the Arduino as the encoder controller is because I need to know which way the robot is moving as I can't discern direction of rotation with only one sensor per wheel. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo full installation.Is there a package to fit my needs that I have just not found yet or is there a package I can modify slightly to fit my needs? Thanks,
L

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204583/interface-code-to-handle-arduino-motor-controller-and-odometry/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try looking at:

- [ros_arduino_bridge](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge/commit/ecff340ffc3f79dc3b45caf2a7d5d3fc5c602881)
- [ros_arduino](https://github.com/tonybaltovski/ros_arduino)

You would have to keep track if the direction of the wheel since you only have one channel but it is possible.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0